# How does indentation work when using includes in pugjs?

Tags: pug, indentation

The pictures below make my problem clear. The indentation does not work well. nav.pug, for example, should be included inside the blur class. That doesn't happen now... . What am I doing wrong?

I seem to do everything according to the documentation. https://pugjs.org/language/includes.html

index.pug file code

```
include ../../3-base-blocks/doctype.pug
  head
    include ../../3-base-blocks/head.pug
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='index.scss')
    script(src='index.js', defer='')
  body
    include ../../3-base-blocks/blur-modal.pug
    include ../../3-base-blocks/blur.pug
      include ../../4-blocks/nav.pug
      include ../../4-blocks/header.pug
      include ../../4-blocks/faq.pug
      include ../../4-blocks/about.pug
    include ../../3-base-blocks/structured-data.pug
```

nav.pug file code

```
.nav
  a.nav__logo-link(href= body.navLink)
    img.nav__logo-img(src= body.navLogo, alt= body.navLogoAlt)
  a.nav__header-link(href= body.navLink)  
    p.nav__header-text= body.navHeader
  .nav__lang-country-flag
    img(src= body.navFlag, alt= body.navAltLogo)
  .hamburger.nav__hamburger.nav__hamburger_position
    span.hamburger__top-bun
    span.hamburger__bottom-bun
```

blur.pug code

```
.blur
```

[result i dont want to have...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbkLQ.png)

Comment: show your code instead of screenshots

Comment: Changed it. Now it is code.

Comment: You can't nest anything inside of an `include`. There should not be anything indented beneath an include.

Comment: Hi sean, thank you for your answer. Can you show documentation that proofs this. :-)

Comment: Hi Sean, your answer is correct. Thank you so much!! :-)